# Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10df73c08) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10df74108)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift3, alamofire

```
    let url = "http://xyz/index_main.php?c=webservices&a=get&e=007"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            //to get status code
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 201:
                    print("example success")
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status)")
                }
            }
            //to get JSON return value
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                print(JSON)
            }
```

**Result :**

```
    {
    "create_by" = 007;
    "create_date" = "2016/06/20";
    "due_date" = "2016/06/22";
    "estimate_time" = "";
    fixer = 007;
    priority = High;
    "project_code" = testing;
    status = "Re-Open";
    "task_id" = 228;
    "task_title" = test;
    tester = 007;
},
    {
    "create_by" = 006;
    "create_date" = "2016/06/23";
    "due_date" = "2016/06/24";
    "estimate_time" = "";
    fixer = 007;
    priority = Critical;
    "project_code" = "tanteida.c";
    status = "In Progress";
    "task_id" = 234;
    "task_title" = testing;
    tester = 006;
}
```

I want to convert to `NSDictionary` and get different Array like `task_id`(array) but I get this error:

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to NSDictionary"

**Please Help me**

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: your result is array ...not dictionary

Comment: yes but i want in dictionary

Comment: What exactly do you want in the array?

Comment: i want to split this array like task_id in array

Comment: You want to convert this to a dictionary where the key is the `task_id` and the value is the dictionary of values?

Comment: i want to print this value into table using different array from this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your response is of `Array` of `Dictionary` not `Dictionary`, so if you want all the dictionary you can access it using loop.

```
if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
    //If you want array of task id you can try like
    let taskArray = array.flatMap { $0["task_id"] as? String }
    print(taskArray)
}
```

Comment: 1 more que can i use taskArray as global varialbe?

Comment: For that you need to declare taskArray as instance variable of your Controller.

Comment: i m new in swift so please tell me how i declare like that var taskArray = Array<any>() but i know this is not right

Comment: Like this way`var taskArray = [String]()`

Comment: Hey Nirav hope you help me, in taskArray sometime get null value from web service that time how to handle?.

Comment: @seggy Then use `flatMap` instead of `map` it will ignore the nil and give you the array of `String` not `String?`.

Comment: i also used flat map but when null value comes than does't work BTW i got the solution  **array.map{($0["task_id"] as? String) ?? ""}** thank you

Comment: @seggy `flatMap` will ignore the nil so you get less object when it is nil and currently the way you are using that will give you empty string if it is nil.

Comment: yes you are right i was get error(cast error) because i am doing like this **msg.flatMap{($0["description"] as? String)!}** now i got it

Comment: @seggy Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you service returns results in form of an array. What you need to do is to cast result to NSArray. Then you can access separate results by index:

```
let JSON = result as! NSArray
let firstResult = results[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1 +**

```
if let resultArray = jsonResponse.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
    let taskArray = resultArray.compactMap { $0["task_id"] as? String }
}
```