# Parsing array literal from JSON in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

I have a PHP script that returns a JSON response in the format of an array literal.

**Example of exactly what it returns:**

```
["school","chess_club"]
```

---

However, I am unable to parse it in Swift after I received the response successfully.

**Code:**

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
print (json)
```

**Error:**

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10a440d88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10a441288).

**Note on duplicate:**

I found this duplicate, [Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10df73c08) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10df74108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461888/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsarrayi-0x10df73c08-to-nsdictionary-0x10d), but I can't figure out how can I use it to fix the error in my situation.

Specifically, I don't get how am I casting it to a NSDictionary since I didn't specify anywhere in my code "NSDictionary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[String:AnyObject]` is a `Dictionary` Object although you didn't specify it. Try this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String]
print (json)
```

Comment: @Panda Please mark it as answer if this help you :)

Comment: Yup, will mark it when it allows in 3 mins time, thanks again!